# Code extract value for each line through the word

Tags: vb.net, filter

textbox1.text =

```
| 212.55.11.51:8080 | vpn | http |
| 212.55.11.52:8080 | rte | http |
| 212.55.11.53:8080 | dfg | http |
| 212.55.11.54:8080 | vpn | http |
| 212.55.11.55:8080 | vpn | http |
| 212.55.11.56:8080 | Tyu | http |
| 212.55.11.57:8080 | RFe | http |
| 212.55.11.58:8080 | vpn | http |
```

I need to work Code. 
When you write the word vpn.
Through textbox2 The pressure on Button.

The IP address is shown located the line. 
An example of the example above to proceed 8 lines contain the number 4 lines with the word vpn.

Display all of the IP Next
212.55.11.51
212.55.11.54
212.55.11.55
212.55.11.58

Inside ListBox

Comment: what have you tried so far? one best way to tackle this is to use a dictionary where the key would be "vpn" for example, then holding a value which would be a list of the ip addresses. then when you use ContainsKey("Vpn") for example, then you can use the key indexer (i.e myDict["Vpn"]) to get back the list value and for each item in the list, add it to the listbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ and `String.Split`:

```
Dim lines = text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim matchingIPs = From line In lines
                  Let tokens = line.Split({"|"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  Let IP = tokens(0).Trim()
                  Let type = tokens(1).Trim()
                  Where type = "vpn"
                  Select IP.Split(":"c)(0).Trim()

listBox1.Items.AddRange(matchingIPs.ToArray())
```